# How can I adjust my IC placement further to route properly?

Tags: pcb, eaglecad, autorouter

I've been trying to place my ICs properly to allow the autorouter to route the ICs with no success, I'm a total beginner at this and I tried routing manually with no success, any hints? The board is 1 layer only.

[image]

Comment: Is it 1 layer only? What about tracks in between the pins? And why do you have so much spacing between the components?

Comment: Yes it's only 1 Layer, I thought giving the autorouter more space to work in means it will more likely success, I have no idea about the tracks

Comment: Well, the autorouter is not always the best option. Especially not if you are not experienced with setting it up properly. What package size is those ICs in? SOIC? what is the minimum track width, maybe you can fit a track in between the pins.

Comment: Try routing yourself. Like Linkyyy said the autorouter is not the best. Why only 1 layer?

Comment: I'll ask my TA about these info, but if I can't fit a track between the pins, how can I improve the placement? to even start routing manually?

Comment: This is an assignment for a project I have to work on, so we're limited by some resources the TAs assigned, one layer.
I have tried routing by myself but I got stuck in a dead end

Comment: One layer is not very strange if OP is going to have the board made by etching or milling.

Comment: @pipe: No, but if its something he will solder himself its probably some bigger package like an SOIC so it would not be a problem to route a track in between the pins. Ive done and etched that myself.

Comment: Realistically, your mistakes are 1) trying to use low density integration when it no longer makes any sense to 2) trying to use a single layer board for a short run project where you'll probably pay for two layers anyway, and all that wasted space would cost more than the layers to begin with.  If you were doing this right, you'd have a few highly capable chips (MCU and/or programmable logic, plus maybe something specialized) often with somewhat flexible pinouts on a *surface mount* board. If it's a one-off perhaps you should wire wrap or point to point wire it, or for curiosity breadboard it.

Comment: @Linkyyy Not sure why you directed that to me. Routing between the pins does not mean two layers.

Comment: That looks truly horrible. Line the chips up so they're all turned the same way, run the Vcc/GND first, add **bypass capacitors** (typically one per logic chip), and then add jumpers as needed to make the remaining signal traces short. You will almost always wind up with a few jumpers on a single-sided board that has a sensible layout.

Comment: Is it just me or does IC6 ONLY have power and ground connected? If so getting rid of it entirely will make things easier. Also where are the decoupling caps? Ditch the autorouter, they are horrible for single sided (and a LOT of work to set up to do well even on a multilayer job). Where are the power connection points? Where are the inputs and outputs? There is more to a circuit then just the chips.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the autorouter is awful. I suggest you lay out the ICs more closely, with the sides that have the most common connections facing each other (meaning if two sides of an IC have many connections, put them side by side to lessen the length of your traces.

It looks like you may be running traces to connect the GND pins. While this isn't inherently bad, you'd want to use a ground pour (use the polygon tool to draw an area around all ICs and name it "GND") to kill the need for those traces and open up the layout to allow you to run more traces.

Comment: I've lined them closer together, does having a ground pour require me to use a 2 layer PCB?

Comment: No, ground pours are per-layer, though on a two layer board, you would want to connect the two pours with vias.

Comment: I've gotten to [this](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-5cJe9smk-tI/XAbYZ_HZ2BI/AAAAAAAAKMo/_UF6cZcUZHEsW1boOPUCAoGtkEh8X-CJgCHMYCw/s0/eagle_2018-12-04_21-41-24.png) , no idea what to do next..

Comment: Post your .sch and .brd to GitHub as gists and link them here, please.

Comment: [There you go](https://github.com/Youssef-Walid98/PCB)

Answer (score 1):

You need to list the constraints you are working under. There have to be some more components on that board, even if only connectors and decoupling caps.
  If you're having a prototype board made, there's typically no additional charge for a 2 sided board, that will then almost always autoroute, even if it's ugly.

If you're not constrained not to do so, you can use zero ohm surface mount resistors to bridge over tracks that form a loop that it's impossible to route out of otherwise, after first positioning the devices so that the majority of connections between pins are satisfied.